# Result of call to 'offset(x:y:)' is unused warning on last modifier inside a function SwiftUI

Tags: function, struct, swiftui

I have a function that sends a GET request to my API and then will parse data into a struct. From there I have `Text` views that use the data from the struct and are set up like this;

```
func pullData(){

...

Text(results.text)
       .offset(y: 10)
       .lineLimit(4)

//Date and time for post
Text(results.created )
       .font(.footnote)
       .fontWeight(.light)
       .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
       .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
       .offset(x: -85, y: 50)

}
```

On the last modifier for each Text view I get the error (example);

> Result of call to 'offset(x:y:)' is unused

When I call the function none of the text views appear in the actual view. I have tired to research this warning/error but haven't found anything remotely close to a solution. The full function looks like this;

```
    var spread = Bool()
     let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8000/areas/sample/")! as URL,
                                             cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                             timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    func pullData(){
            let headers = [
                //"Authorization": "token \(tokenData ?? "nope")",
                "Authorization": "token 9a591156c0b828e2cc80b7c7cba2972ff8eb08df",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                "Postman-Token": "53853353-f547-410a-b289-e3c4ced8e426"
            ]

            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error)
                }
                guard let data = data else {return}

                do{
                    let JSONFromServer = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                    print(JSONFromServer)
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let postDetailsDataArray = try decoder.decode(postDetails.self, from: data)
                    print(postDetailsDataArray.results)
                    for results in postDetailsDataArray.results{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            //Account Pic Post and Other Stuff In The HStack
                      HStack {
                         Button(action: {}) {
                                 ImageWithActivityIndicator(imageURL: results.author?.avatar ?? "")
                                 .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                 .clipShape(Circle())
                                 .offset(x: -75, y: 0)
                             }
                             Text(results.author?.name ?? "Annon")
                                 .offset(x: -75)
                             Button(action: {}) {
                              Image("BookMark").offset(x: 70)
                             }
                             Button(action: {}) {
                              Image("more-vertical").offset(x: 70)
                             }

                      }.offset(y: 65)

                        //Description code (pulls data from api)
                         Text(results.text)
                         //.padding(.bottom, 0)
                         .offset(y: 10)
                         .lineLimit(4)

                         //Image From Post Stuff
                         if results.image == nil{
                             print("no image")
                         }else{
                         ImageWithActivityIndicator(imageURL: results.image ?? "")
                         .offset(y: 50)
                         .scaledToFit()
                         }
                            //Date and time for post
                            Text(results.created )
                             .font(.footnote)
                             .fontWeight(.light)
                             .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                             .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                             .offset(x: -85, y: 50)

                            for comments in results.comments{
                                print(comments)
                                    //Comment View Code using Lists

                             List(results.comments){ comments in
                                 HStack{
                                     ImageWithActivityIndicator(imageURL: comments.author?.avatar ?? "")
                                     .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
                                 }
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("Failed to decode:", error)
                }
            })
            dataTask.resume()
        }
```

I am calling the function inside the view like so;

```
var body: some View {
        //Smaller UI
                       VStack {

                    ...

                }.onAppear() {
                self.pullData()
           }
        }
```

The data is parsed successfully because I am able to print out the data in the struct. I have tried to find ways around this warning/error such as moving the text views to the view instead of having them inside the function but I ran into other issues with that. I'm new to SwiftUI so any help in as always appreciated!

Comment: Any SwiftUI view (like, Text, VStack, etc.) must be injected in view hierarchy from some of view builder (in your case it is only `body`). Your `pullData` is called from a callback out of view hierarchy construction, so all views appeared in it are just lost values. (SwiftUI views are not objects, they do not work like just `addSubview`)

Comment: @Asperi How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score -1):

Your function must return View for you to see it.

```
func pullData() -> some View { return Text("some View") }
```

Right now it isn't returning anything at all, all that view that you have written in your function is unused, that's why the result is unused.

And use it like this to see

```
struct User: Codable {
var title: String = "" 
}

struct ContentView: View {

@State var users = User()

var body: some View {
    VStack{
    pullData()
    }
}


func pullData()-> some View{

    let string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
     let url = URL(string: string)!
     let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print("error getting data from url"); return }

            if let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data!){
                    self.users = result

            }

    }.resume()

    return Text(users.title)

}

}
```

Comment: How would this work when I need to use a `for` loop to get to other part of my struct.